# How to change value in listview of lable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview, label

Hello i need a help with listview control
here is a listview code below:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
         GroupItemCount="3"   OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
                           ID="groupPlaceHolder" />
                        </div>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <div style="clear: both;">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" 
                                  ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
                        </div>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="store-l">
                            <p class="exe-title">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
                             </asp:Label>  </p>
                            <center> 
            <a href="View.aspx?Iv=<%# Eval("Id") %>"><asp:Image ID="Image2" 
                  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl")%>' runat="server" 
                               Height="175" Width="280"></asp:Image></a>
     </center>
                            <p class="exe-title">
                                <%# Eval("Description")%>
                       <a href="ViewResult.aspx?Iv=<%# Eval("Id") %>">View Result</a>
                            </p>                           
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                        <div style="clear: both"/>
                    </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

There is Label1 I want to change value of this via code. There are 12 fixed values and i need to add these 12 values as below:

```
1. day 1 
2. day two 
3. day three 
4. day four 
5. day fiv etc.
```

I want to add this value in lable1 using code. programming language is c#. hope somebody has a solution for doing this please let me know how can i do this and share you code with me

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far. Why should we share our code, put out what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic approach should be like the following:

In the ItemDataBound event handler for the ListView, check to see what kind of template it is. If it is an ItemTemplate, then find the control Label1 using e.Item.FindControl("Label1") and cast it to a Label type. Then you are free to do with it what you want. So you can assign it to a Label variable. Something like this should work:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label Label1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");

    Label1.Text = "day 1"; //do whatever you want with the Label here
}
```

Also, you have to hook up your ListView with this event handler either in the declarative markup or in Page_Load or another event. If you do it in declarative markup, just add the following attribute to your ListView tag:

```
OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound"
```

Hope that helps.

Check out this link for an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: that i know but i didnt get how can i change value of ever ever row label value